# Arm64 SHA512 intrinsics fail to compile with GCC ("target specific option mismatch")

Tags: gcc, arm64, sha512

Consider the following source file `test-sha512.c`, using SHA512 intrinsics on Arm64 (aarch64):

```
#include <arm_neon.h>
const uint64_t data[256] = {0,};

void test()
{
    uint64x2_t a = vld1q_u64(data);
    a = vsha512h2q_u64(a, a, a);
}
```

On Ubuntu 22.10 (virtual machine on an MacBook M1), with gcc 12.2.0, I have the error "inlining failed in call to ‘always_inline’" and "target specific option mismatch":

```
$ gcc -c test-sha512.c -march=armv8-a+sha3
In file included from test-sha512.c:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/include/arm_neon.h: In function ‘test’:
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/include/arm_neon.h:29671:1: error: inlining failed in call to ‘always_inline’ ‘vsha512h2q_u64’: target specific option mismatch
29671 | vsha512h2q_u64 (uint64x2_t __a, uint64x2_t __b, uint64x2_t __c)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test-sha512.c:7:9: note: called from here
    7 |     a = vsha512h2q_u64(a, a, a);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/12/include/arm_neon.h:29671:1: error: inlining failed in call to ‘always_inline’ ‘vsha512h2q_u64’: target specific option mismatch
29671 | vsha512h2q_u64 (uint64x2_t __a, uint64x2_t __b, uint64x2_t __c)
      | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test-sha512.c:7:9: note: called from here
    7 |     a = vsha512h2q_u64(a, a, a);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

With clang 15.0.6, it compiles correctly and a full SHA512 implementation using Arm64 intrinsics and compiled with clang works correctly.

```
$ clang -c test-sha512.c -march=armv8-a+sha3
```

Note: the Arm architecture defines distinct features for SHA1, SHA256, SHA512 and SHA3. However, gcc and clang know `crypto`, `sha2` and `sha3` only. The SHA512 instructions (cryptographically part of SHA2) are activated with `sha3`. Weird. Anyway...

The similar Arm64 intrinsics for AES, SHA1 and SHA256 compile correctly with gcc. The problem is specific to SHA512.

Other tests, without success, same error:

- The error "target specific option mismatch" may suggest a misinterpretation of the `-march` option. I tried with all Armv8 options (`-march=armv8-a+fp+simd+crypto+crc+lse+fp16+rcpc+rdma+dotprod+aes+sha2+sha3+sm4+fp16fml+sve+profile+rng+memtag+sb+ssbs+predres+sve2+sve2-sm4+sve2-aes+sve2-sha3+sve2-bitperm+tme+i8mm+f32mm+f64mm+bf16+flagm+pauth+ls64+mops`) and with `-march=armv9-a`.
- Using `-march=native`, considering that the M1 supports SHA512.
- Using `-mcpu=neoverse-v1` or `-mcpu=neoverse-n2` or other known Arm cores which support SHA512.
- Various types of optimization options.
- Tried various (but not all) suggestions from `gcc --target-help`.

Is this a known error? I did not find any reference online about this error on Arm64 SHA512 intrinsics.

EDIT: SHA256 intrinsics also fail with the same error. Only SHA1 intrinsics work. My previous tests with SHA256 were made using clang, sorry.

EDIT 2: SHA256 intrinsics work with `-march=armv8-a+sha2+crypto` but not with `-march=armv8-a+sha2`. SHA512 still don't work, even with all `-march` options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SHA3/SHA512 extension is documented by ARM only for  ARMv8.2-A onward.  As such, gcc requires you to use `-march=armv8.2-a+sha3` (or `v8.3-a`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, it works. 

Nonetheless, this -march stuff is really weird with gcc. The idea of the Arm FEAT_xxx is that you don't really care about the arch version, you just care about the individual features. This is why armv8-a+sha3 works with clang. Also, using "sha3" for sha512 is insane since Arm has distinct FEAT_SHA512 and FEAT_SHA3. And SHA-512 is part of the SHA-2 family, not SHA-3. Gcc is very wrong. 

Anyway, you found the right options for gcc, thanks.

Comment: @ThierryLelegard: It is a bit weird, but I think there is a certain logic to it.  In the Architecture Reference Manual, the extension is consistently named "ARMv8.2-SHA".  So ARM considers it not as an extension to ARMv8-A in general, but to ARMv8.2 in particular, and GCC is being consistent with that.

Comment: @ThierryLelegard:  Moreover, SHA-512 and SHA-3 may be separate feature bits in the register, but they're documented as a single architectural extension, so I think in order to conform to the spec, a chip has to implement them both together.  So it's just that GCC has chosen to name this extension as `sha3` for short, which is somewhat annoying, but the official name "ARMv8.2-SHA" is more ambiguous, and `sha3-and-sha512` would be verbose.

Comment: This is no longer true. Arm has dropped this "extension" model for some time. They have a "feature" model. All features are named FEAT_xxx. Features FEAT_SHA256, FEAT_SHA512 and FEAT_SHA3 are individually identified in system register ID_AA64ISAR0_EL1. It is definitely allowed to implement FEAT_SHA512 without FEAT_SHA3, not only because they use distinct bits in the register, but because this is simply allowed. So, gcc is wrong in its classification. See project https://github.com/lelegard/arm-cpusysregs for more details on identifying individual FEAT_xxx.

Comment: @ThierryLelegard: Oh, I see, I was looking at an old version of the manual.  You're correct about the current version.  Still, the gcc option syntax was presumably defined when the "extension" model was in effect, and so it might be hard to change it now without breaking compatibility with existing scripts and makefiles.  But anyway, if you feel strongly, you know where to find the gcc bug tracker...